# How can I solve this race condition involving PlacePicker?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have a race condition between the PlacePicker activity and my own activity that I want to start immediately after PlacePicker ends.

Here is how my app works:
It begins in PlaceActivity.  In PlaceActivity's onStart, I connect to the GoogleAPI.  In onConnected, I use Places to determine the user's location.  If the location has a probability of less than .8, it invokes the PlacePicker (which is it's own activity).  The Placepicker is created with startActivityForResult.  Within the corresponding onActivityResult, RatingsActivity is started and is passed the place from the PlacePicker.  The problem is that there is a race between PlaceActivity restarting after PlacePicker stops, and the start of RatingsActivity.  How do I fix this?  I know I could require the user to press another button to find their location, but I would much rather it happen automatically in onStart.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    detectCurrentPlace();
}

public void detectCurrentPlace() {
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

    //Find the most probable place
    //If prob is greater than threshold, assume this is the correct place.
    //Otherwise, open placepicker
    final double thresh = .8;

    //intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.name", mostProbPlace.getName());
    //intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.address", mostProbPlace.getAddress());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
            double highestProb = 0;
            PlaceLikelihood mostProbPlace = null;
            for(PlaceLikelihood p : placeLikelihoods) {
                if(p.getLikelihood() > highestProb) {
                    highestProb = p.getLikelihood();
                    mostProbPlace = p;
                }
                StringBuffer types = new StringBuffer();
                for (int type : p.getPlace().getPlaceTypes()) {
                    types.append(", " + type);
                }
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has liklihood: %g", p.getPlace().getName(), p.getLikelihood()));
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Website: '%s; Types: %s", p.getPlace().getWebsiteUri(), types));
            }
            placeLikelihoods.release();

            //Log.i(TAG, "Probability of place: " + mostProbPlace.getLikelihood());
            if(highestProb > thresh) {
                //I'm not sure if this line is right
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RatingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.name", mostProbPlace.getPlace().getName());
                intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.address", mostProbPlace.getPlace().getAddress());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else {
               createPlacePicker();
            }

            placeLikelihoods.release();
        }


    });
}

public void createPlacePicker() {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    try {
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(context), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

    } catch(GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "REPAIRABLE_SERVICES");
    } catch(GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "NOTAVAILABLE_SERVICES");
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RatingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.name", place.getName());
            intent.putExtra("com.parse.starter.address", place.getAddress());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the race condition is caused by the fact you are running `detectCurrentPlace` every time `onStart` is called.

I think you just need to store the state of your `PlaceActivity` when the activity is started, so you can modify the behaviour of `onStart` depending upon whether it is being called from the launch, or as a result of the return from `PlacePicker`.

```
class PlaceActivity {
   boolean mRunningPlacePicker;

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      if (mRunningPlacePicker) {
        // we've returned from placepicker - don't run the detectCurrentPlace again 
        // because RatingsActivity has already launched from onActivityResult 
         ...
       } else {
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      // save the state in case Android destroys our activity
      outState.putBoolean("mRunningPlacePicker", mRunningPlacePicker);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      // restore the state
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
          mRunningPlacePicker = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("mRunningPlacePicker");
      }
  }
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
      detectCurrentPlace();
  }

  public void detectCurrentPlace() {
     // do your deciding...
     result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
          ...
          if (highestProb > thresh) {
            ...
          } else {
             // save the fact we are running the place picker
             mRunningPlacePicker = true;
             createPlacePicker();
          }
  }

}
```

Comment: That should work.  It does seem wasteful though to start an activity just to stop it immediately.  Is this something that developers normally run into?

Comment: Just adding finish() at the end of onActivityResult also seems to work.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's actually fairly common to create intermediate Activities that check some logic, launch something else and then immediately finish - Android copes with it just fine. Yes, adding `finish()` will prevent the activity from restarting - I just assumed you needed to go back to it at some point from  `RatingsActivity`. If not, finishing from onActivityResult is perfectly acceptable.